# Problrms reading csv files via numpy and pandas

Tags: python, csv, numpy, path

I have a folder with a certain path and I want to go through all the folders within this folder. Each subfolder contains multiple files of which I only want a certain ".csv" file. I succeed in reading the different folders and selecting the correct file, but when I try to open it (bith with pandas and numpy), I get an IOError stating that the corresponding file doesn't exist..

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

path = "some_path"
data_list = os.listdir(path) 

array = []

for file in data_list:                                                          
  if file.endswith("name_requirement"):
      array.append(function(file))


file_filter = "second_name_requirement"


def function(second_path):

  file_list = os.listdir(path + "\\" + str(second_path))

  average = 0

  for file in file_list:
     if str(file)[-20:-4] == file_filter:
         measurements =  pd.read_csv(file, delimiter = ";", skiprows = 1, usecols = [1])           
#        measurements = np.loadtxt(file, delimiter =";", skiprows =1)

.....
```

`

Comment: Can you print out file right before you do the read and confirm that the file exists? My intuition is that the file is only the filename and doesn't include the entire path.

Comment: I do print the file names of each file in the secondary folders in order to check, and what I get is: file1 , file2,...,filename.csv,... and then the IOError saying filename.csv does not exist

Comment: You have to include the full path to the file.

Comment: I guess you have to add the path to the read_csv as well. Have you tried that already? list_dir only seems to return the file names relative to the folder you specified. So you should probably open them like read_csv(path + "\\" + str(second_path) + "\\" + file, ...)

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys it was indeed a problem with the path!